# how to filter the lines contain at least one "x" for the first nine characters

Tags: linux, unix, text-processing

for example if we have `txt` as below

```
drwxr-sr-x  7 abcdefgetdf 
drwxr-sr-x  7 abcdef123123sa
drwxr-sr--  7 abcdefgetdf
drwxr-sr--  7 abcdeadfvcxvxcvx
drwxr-sr-x  7 abcdef123ewlld
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title strictly:

```
awk 'substr($0, 1, 9) ~ /x/' txt
```

Though if you're interested in files with at least one execute permission bit set, then perhaps `find -perm /0111` would be something to look into.

Comment: @James, ah true, kiitos.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
ls -l | awk '$1~/x/'
```

---

`$1~/x/` - regular expression match, accepts only lines with the 1st field containing `x` character

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a one liner that just checked the first 9 (or 10) characters for 'x'. But this little script does the trick. Uses "ls -l" as input instead of a file, but it's trivial to pass in a file to filter instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l | while read line
do
  perms="${line:0:10}"
  if [[ "${perms}" =~ "x" ]]; then
    echo "${line}"
  fi
done
```